# Configuration management tool selection

Tags: configuration-management

Our organization has below workflow.

Dev prepares base package (set of executables with base configuration embedded in code) --> QA tests that --> after successful testing, QA provides this package to Engineering team --> Engineering team make changes to client specific config files (which they maintain locally) and rebundle config files with  package client wise  --> delivery to respective clients

There are lot of clients and hence lot of client  specific config files. Is there any tool which keep track of configuration files client wise, able to edit files in GUI and keep versions for them, bundle specific files at end and make a final package client wise ?

Thanks for your time.
Sachin

Comment: You didn't mention what technology stack you are currently using - that _may_ guide some of the discussion.

Comment: base package is made from binaries made out of c, java code. config files are text files like config.ini, client.cfg etc

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Comment: How are you handling these config files now? Are they in source control? Are the config files vastly different, or could they be algorithmically built per client? Chef is an amazing configuration management tool that would allow you to not only build and apply these config files, but also distribute them.